# I want to[ "select the 'user_id ' where product_id like '$productid' and max_value(bid_amount) from table 'bid_products']

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my database:
I want to sort row by the max value of bid amount and product id.

[image: Database]

my code using Codeigniter or PHP:

```
$product_id=$data;
unset($data['product_id']);
$win= "SELECT user_id FROM bid_products WHERE product_id like '$product_id' and MAX(bid_amount)";
$winner=$this->db->query($win);
$user_id =$winner['user_id'];
```

or

```
this->db->select('user_id');
$this->db->from('bid_products');
$this->db->where('product_id',$product_id);
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query;
```

Comment: Not sure what the minus is for, other than spamming all the possible types.  This is really a mysql question

Comment: Is `$data` an array? Looks like it. You need to know what kind of data-type you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no possibility for same bid_amount and bid is always increasing, this query should do the job:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM bid_products 
WHERE product_id = '$product_id' 
ORDER BY bid_amount DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```